# How to create a searchable drop down list in mvc5?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to make my current dropdown lists(scaffolded by mvc) searchable.

I added this script but it didn't help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("select").searchable({
            maxListSize: 100,
            maxMultiMatch: 50,
            exactMatch: false,
            wildcards: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            latency: 200,
            warnMultiMatch: 'top {0} matches ...',
            warnNoMatch: 'no matches ...',
            zIndex: 'auto'
       });
});
```

These are my dropdown lists

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerID, "CustomerID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CustomerID", null, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VideoID, "VideoID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("VideoID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VideoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VideoID, "VideoID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("VideoID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control",@class="select2" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VideoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".select2").select2();
    });
    </script>

<select class="js-example-basic-single">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```